# OpenGL shadow mapping - shadow is in wrong place

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, render, shadow

I have a problem with shadows, and i do not see any mistake in my code.
It is all visible on the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZXEPLIYGNM&feature=youtu.be

My light source is inside the not-textured ball and it is moving.
The shadows are replaced

Basically:

- During shadow pass I use the same program as in render pass
- My shadow texture is the same size as my viewport ( 1920 x 1200 )
- My light source is point light
- I use only fragment and vertex shader (no geometry and tesselation)
- There is only one light source
- My depth mvp matrix is LightProjection * LightCamera * MeshModelMatrix
- My projection is:
  Field of view  90
  near plane     0.1
  far plane      5000000.0
- ViewportRatio  1
- Camera head    (0.0,1.0,0.0)
- I use bias matrix in correct way
- graphics nVidia nvm3100m driver version. 304.117
  **- I have displayed additional viewport to see the scene from the light point of view**

All my code is behind abstractions so I chose from it all the things (I think) which can influent shadows. Point light works just fine, but shadows are in wrong places.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZXEPLIYGNM&feature=youtu.be

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330

struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 intensity;
    mat4 mvp;
};

...
out vec4 fColor;
in vec4 vVertexWorldSpace;
...
uniform texture2D uShadowTexUnit;
...
uniform Light uLight;
...
vec4 ambient = vec4(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.0);
...
float calculateShadow(vec4 lightPosition, sampler2D shadowMap) {
    vec3 shadowMapUV = lightPosition.xyz / lightPosition.w;
    float shadowMapDepth = texture(shadowMap, shadowMapUV.xy).x;

    if ((shadowMapDepth < shadowMapUV.z - 0.00001))                                                                 
        return 0.1;                                                                         
    else                                                                                    
        return 1.0;     
}


void main() {
   ...
   lightDepth = uLight.mvp * vVertexWorldSpace;
   shadow = calculateShadow(lightDepth, uShadowMaps);
   ...
   fColor = vec4(shadow * colorDiffuse.xyz,1.0) + colorAmbient;
}
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330
...
layout(location = 0) in vec4 aPosition;
...
out vec4 vVertexWorldSpace;

uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

void main() {
   vec4 vertexWorldspace = uModelMatrix * aPosition;
   vVertexWorldSpace = vertexWorldSpace;

   gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uViewMatrix * vertexWorldspace;
}
```

My camera settings in Light class constructor:

```
   Light::Light(glm::vec3 position,
                glm::vec4 intensity):mIntensity(intensity),
                                     mShadowTextureUnit(31){
   mShadowCamera = new Camera(glm::vec3(position), //position
                              glm::vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), // lookAt point - always 0
                              glm::vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0), //head
                              glm::radians(90.0), //field of view angle
                              1.0, // viewport ratio
                              0.1, // near plane
                              2000.0); //far plane
   }
```

My rendering code in mesh:

```
class Mesh {

     ...

     glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
     glm::mat4 cameraMatrix;
     glm::mat4 projectionMatrix;

     ...

     void Mesh::render () {

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + fillwave_texture_unit);
        mTextureRegion->getTexture()->bind();
        mProgram->uniformPush("uDiffuseTextureUnit", fillwave_texture_unit);

        glm::mat4 eye = mLight->getShadowCamera()->getEye();
        glm::mat4 projection = mLight->getShadowCamera()->getProjection();
        glm::vec4 lightTranslation = mLight->getShadowCamera()->getTranslation();
        glm::vec4 lightIntensity = mLight->getIntensity()();

        //MVP model
        shader->uniformPush ("uModelMatrix", modelMatrix);
        shader->uniformPush ("uCameraMatrix", cameraMatrix);
        shader->uniformPush ("uProjectionMatrix", projectionMatrix);

        //MVP light
        shader->uniformPush ("uLight.position", lightTranslation);
        shader->uniformPush ("uLight.intensity", lightIntensity);
        shader->uniformPush ("uShadowTexUnit", mLight->getTextureUnit());

        glm::mat4 biasMatrix(
        0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
        );

        shader->uniformPush ("uLight.mvp",biasMatrix *
                                           projection * // projection
                                           eye * // camera matrix
                                           m); // model matrix of this mesh
     }
}
```

Comment: Updated the video, updated the code. Additional debug window added to see the scene from the camera point of view.

Comment: I have finally got it work. The resolution of the window was set to1920X1200, also texture size was equal 1920x1200. My screen was 1440x900 so I was rendering the screenv 1440x900 screen to texture 1920x1200. This was the reason that the shadow was moved. the texture was partially filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got it work. The resolution of the window was set to a 1920X1200, also texture size was equal 1920x1200. My screen was 1440x900 so I was rendering the screen 1440x900 to texture 1920x1200. This was the reason that the shadow was moved. the texture was partially filled.

[image: bottom left - camera view, bottom right - depth from camera view]